# asp.net fast upload slow server processing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am doing a file upload with a POST ajax call from JS client side to my receiveFile.aspx server side. (Say for a file size of 5MB)

Ajax reports file progress very fast. The file is uploaded in 1-3 seconds. (I slowed down my network speed to be sure and yes I get progress reports nicely)

However after completing the POST request i have to wait for about 5-10 seconds for the receiveFile.aspx to complete the request and respond back.

ReceiveFile is very basic

```
Private Sub ReceiveFile()

    Dim targetFileName = "uploadedFile.jpg"

    Using ms = New MemoryStream()
        Dim buffer = New Byte(4096) {}
        Dim bytesRead = -1

        Do Until bytesRead = 0
            bytesRead = Context.Request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
        Loop

        Using fs = New FileStream(targetFileName, FileMode.Create)
            ms.WriteTo(fs)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

I have debugged this and seen that

1. The ReceiveFile does not start until POST is completed, so IIS waits
   for the whole request to complete
2. The call hangs at **Context.Request.InputStream**, waiting the data to be fully loaded to InputStream

If i use **Context.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream** instead, it will slowly process the stream as data is available but the end result is the same, takes 5-10 seconds to get the whole stream.

This is my question. The file stream has already been loaded to ISS. Why does it wait another 5-10 seconds as if the file is being loaded again from client?

Is there anything I can do to speed things up?

Edit: File Upload code

```
var fileName = "sampleFileName.jpg"
var reader = new FileReader;
var UploadProgress = 0;

reader.onloadend = (e) => {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", (e) => {
        UploadProgress = (e.loaded / e.total * 100).toDecimal(0);
    }, false);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {

            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                //fail
            }else{
                //success
            }

        }
    };

    xhr.open("POST", "URL of receiveFile.aspx", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", file.type);
    xhr.send(reader.result);
}

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

Comment: Are you sure the results you are seeing for the file upload are not, in fact, misleading? That is, your analysis assumes that the file should be available to read on the basis of the AJAX call returning so quickly; I would wonder if the AJAX call is returning before the file is uploaded (as if it were behaving asynchronously). Could you post your upload code?

Comment: Post updated. When i slow down the network speed I see the progress being updated steadly. When I include timestamps to server side code to debug I see that the server side code begins running only after 100% upload is reported. So I assume the progress reports are accurate